# Authentication Between Two Separate Web Applications

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I have two web applications that live on different web servers but if you're authenticated in web app A then the user should also be authenticated in web app B. The inverse is not true, web app A is the "master" authenticator. So its basically single sign on. I have setup Spring Security on app B, but app A will not have Spring configured since its out of my control. Anyone have any ideas on what app A can send to the Spring based app B in order to tell that a user is authenticated in app A? It doesn't have to be a Spring solution but must be java based. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both applications use spring, the simplest way is to use its [http invoker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) mechanism, and exchange some tokens. What will these tokens be exactly depends on your needs. You can use SSL + a client certificate, or you can use OAuth, or a simple authentication (still over ssl).

Answer (score 0):

you could use some sort of openId on A, so a user on B could ask the user to sign in with A as the provider (like our beloved stack overflow), and then B could use 'remember me' semantics so that doesn't need to happen with every login.

A could stand up some sort of webservice that you could access programmatically from B, but B would need to ask the user for credentials to transmit to A.  (unless both apps are on the same domain, you cannot use cookies; if they are on the same domain you can use cookies).

Either way work needs to be done on A.